# Battery replacement on laptop

Tags: voltage, amperage, batteries

In my way to replace my laptop battery, I have question about compatibility.

- My old *original* battery has the following information:
  Li-Ion, Rating: +10.8V ~ 4400mAh, 48Wh
- The battery slot on my laptop has the following information:
  +19V ~ 4.74A, 90W
- The battery I'm looking to buy has the following information:
  14.8V ~ 5200mAh

*Question:*

- What does the "+" sign mean before the voltage value?
- Can I buy this battery for my laptop?

Thanks

**EDIT 1:
Seriously? Down vote without a comment? Why?**

**EDIT 2:
Of course I have looked on the manufacturer website but it is too buggy, non user friendly, search-engine-less website. I can't find information on their website, this is why I'm asking help from the community.**

**EDIT 3: 
I found a battery **11.1V ~ 6600MAH** at a local store. The seller told me that the **14.8V** will be supported by my laptop but it will not be recharged because the motherboard won't deliver the required voltage.

However the **11.1V** battery is ok because the ratio **11.1/10.8** is too small so it will be recharged.

The Ampere is not a problem.

Comment: What does the laptop manufacturer say about the types of batteries suitable for that model laptop?

Comment: Don't ask me to look at the manufacturer crappy website (waste of time)

Comment: You can use the battery. There would nothing wrong happens with your laptop. But for the safety purpose you should have to read the manual and choose according to there requirements.

Comment: @redsonic - then you should be expecting that anyone answering is making an uninformed guess.

Comment: @SHASWAT There is no manual with our days laptops.

Comment: Interesting: Looking up product details from the manufacturer is a *waste of time*, yet asking people to speculate based on sketchy (and apparently incorrect, i.e. the 19 Volt figure) information doesn't seem to be a waste of others' time?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh calm down and read my comment carefully. What is wast of time is the buggy, non user friendly, search-engine-less manufacturer website. I can't find information on their website, this is why I'm taking this way asking help from the community.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, laptop batteries have to be designed to work with a particular make and model of laptop computer. They generally include proprietary circuitry that communicates with the laptop.

For the battery you are planning on buying, if it's vendor explicitly certifies that it will work with your specific make and model of laptop then it should be OK - so long as you are sure the vendor is trustworthy and will reimburse you for any damage the battery causes.

I would be concerned about the variation in voltages you have identified.

- 19 V is a typical voltage for an AC/DC power supply used to charge the battery in-place.
- 14.8 V is a typical value for a laptop li-ion battery.

When replacing a 10.8V Battery with a 14.8V battery I would want to be 100% sure that the laptop was explicitly designed to be able to work with batteries of those two voltages.

Comment: +1 for answering a question, that others just voted down and passed by...

Comment: @redGrittyBrick Right! my AC/DC is 19V ~ 4.74A Looking on internet batteries for my x72jr I can see that batteries voltage vary between 10.8V and 14.8V which I think is reassuring.